# Laravel Nova Model Large Database Pull - Wanting to pull a very large database fail

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-nova

**Current Code in my model**

```
        return $this->belongsToMany(Names::class, 'table_id', 'First_name', 'Last_name');
```

**Error**

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 184218728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9192 bytes)

**Question**

Can I query the database incrementally? How can I have a less demanding request from the DB but still load everything queried from the table?

**Use**

This is to be used in a Laravel Nova card drop-down menu, and search. To attach to other posts that I have to do.

**Solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent may not be the right solution for bigger datasets in simple use-cases (obviously with tuning and caching Eloquent could work well with larger datasets).

The problems when querying large datasets through Eloquent is that each row in that dataset needs to be returned as an Eloquent Model.

Alternate options include using Repositories for custom queries (look into Repository patterns), caching eloquent, pagination etc.

Comment: Thank you - will do